# Delete file from local system

Tags: javascript, file

I would like to know if there is any chance of manipulating (delete) the contents of a folder from a browser: be it a page's JS or a chrome extension.

Comment: Due to obvious security risks this ***IS NOT*** possible.

Comment: Yeah sure - this will do it (sometimes)... `<html><head><title>Please do this</title></head><body>Please open an explorer window, highlight the contents of folder [insert-folder-name-here] and press shift-delete.  Thank you.</body></html>`  Just save that to a HTML file and upload it to your server.  It's the closest thing but I think it's alright ;)

Comment: From a Chrome extension maybe, but certainly not from in-page JavaScript.

Comment: @David that's what i'm looking for: through an extension, but still i don't believe it's possible

Comment: I don't believe it's possible either.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "completely with only the browser's execution," No.  This is a large security risk.  Now if you were to add something like a local daemon, listening on a port that the browser can send a command to, then yes (i.e. a node.js process)

Comment: I want to avoid creating a local script to run on client's machines. If it could be an extension it would be great to integrate with the site

Comment: NPAPI plugins had this ability, but they are discontinued:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi#security-considerations